# Switching between editor and terminal window intermittently fails in vim

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, vim

Maybe I'm just using vim `:term` feature the wrong way but the `ctr+w`-`ctr+w` command does not always work on my Ubuntu set up when I try to switch between the terminal and the editor. I can't figure out why.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Solved in
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740527/problems-with-vim-while-switching-between-open-files

Basically just need to add in .vimrc

```
set hidden
```